# Can a torsion-free group be quasi-isometric to a torsion group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, torsion

I have looked around in the literature on group theory and geometric group theory and this looks to be an open question as far as I can tell (by torsion group, I mean as usual a group in which every element has finite order).

I was wondering if anyone has recently made any progress on this question or if there is some review article which looks at the possibilities?

Comment: The trivial group is both torsion-free and torsion. But apart from this exception I think it's an open question. Already, one can ask if being torsion is a QI-invariant.

Comment: If torsion is in fact an invariant under quasi-isometries, wouldn't that give a negative answer to my question?

Comment: Yes of course. But on the other hand, proving that my question has a negative answer might be easier. Of course which question is harder depends on what's true!

Comment: One can also ask if every finitely generated group is quasi-isometric to a torsion-free group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The answer is no. Indeed it follows from Eskin-Fisher-Whyte that every group QI to a lamplighter group (finite)$\wr\mathbf{Z}$ has an infinite locally finite normal subgroup. I also guess that $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{F}_p[t])$ is a counterexample for $d\ge 3$ but I doubt it's known.

Comment: @YCor: Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of many open questions in geometric group theory related to quasi-isometries.  Proving things about invariance under quasi-isometries is generically quite tricky, as quasi-isometries do not even need to be continuous.  Some other open questions:

- Is the Haagerup property invariant under quasi-isometries? (see comment by YCor for recent work on this one)
- Is the rapid decay property invariant under quasi-isometries?
- Is the property of having uniform exponential growth invariant under quasi-isometries?
- Are random finitely presented groups quasi-isometry rigid?
- How can fundamental groups of compact $3$-manifolds be classified up to quasi-isometry?

Comment: The first one (on Haagerup) has been settled [by Carette](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5446) by combining work of Whyte [on QI between generalized Baumslag-Solitar groups) and myself–Valette (on the Haagerup property for generalized Baumslag-Solitar groups). But I'm not sure Whyte result on which it relies is confirmed. It roughly says "*if 2 generalized BS groups (+ assumptions) have their associated acting groups at finite Hausdorff distance, then they are QI*", so in principle it's not the hardest part of Whyte's preprint (the hardest part, not needed here, goes the reverse direction).